# How to set a new range variable to one cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below that works (almost)

```
Sub Find_PhaseCode_Cell2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newrng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Control budget ")
    With ws
        Set rng = Range("b57:b64")
        With rng
            For x = 57 To 64
                If Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then
                    Debug.Print Cells(x, 2).Address
                End If
            Next x
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

where the debug.print statement is, I would like that to be variable *newrng*.

If I try to set that `set newrng = Cells(x,2).address`, I get an error:

> object required

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `.address`.  All you need is this: `Set newrng = Cells(x, 2)`

Comment: that gives me the cells value, but i really want the address. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's within a 'With' statement so you should be referencing the members by prefixing a '.'

Also don't forget to use direct referencing (i.e. wb.Worksheets)

The following should be an example for you...

```
Sub Find_PhaseCode_Cell2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newrng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Control budget ")

    With ws.Range("B57:B64")
        For x = 57 To 64
            If .Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then
                Set newrng = .Cells(x, 2)
                Debug.Print newrng.Address
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i originally tried that but it returns a text string "05" when i put the period in, and it does that 8 times. im familiar with using the period within a with statement but it doesn't work for some reason. and when i try the debug.print newrng.address, it comes up 8 times as $C$113 - $C$120) when it should be referencing column B.

Comment: That's because newrng is set relative to column B.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix was not to declare newrng as a range. I left it as a variant, and the code below works now.

```
Sub Find_PhaseCode_Cell2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newrng
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Control budget ")
    With ws
        Set rng = Range("b57:b64")
        With rng
            For x = 57 To 64
                If Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then
                    Debug.Print Cells(x, 2).Address
                    newrng = Cells(x, 2).Address
                    MsgBox newrng
                End If
            Next x
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that all your `With` statements are useless unless you beginn a statement with a dot `.`  like `.Cells`. I highly recommend to read about how `With` statements actuall work.